# Java Process Builder - How to Sort 2 files before Diff

Tags: java, process, command-line-interface, processbuilder

I have a Java process that finds the diff between 2 CSVs. It returns the rows that were added/changed/deleted.

The primary part of the code is the following:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/diff", file1.toString(), file2.toString());
Process process;
        
try
{
    process = pb.start();
}
...
```

The problem is, the diff logic will not be accurate if the files are not sorted beforehand. To illustrate, say I have the following 2 datasets with the following:

```
DATA 1               DATA2
"10000,x,x"          "10000,y,y"
"10000,y,y"          "10000,x,x"
```

The lists are the same, but they are in different orders. As a consequence, my current logic will think that the row with ID `10000` was changed. The correct way to apply the diff would be on the sorted data like so...

```
DATA 1               DATA2
"10000,x,x"          "10000,x,x"
"10000,y,y"          "10000,y,y"
```

My question is, what is a working implementation in Java that is equivalent to the following...

`diff -> sort(file1) sort(file2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there's a relatively straightforward `bash` solution...

```
String cmd = "diff <(sort " + file1.toString() + ") <(sort " + file2.toString() + ")";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", cmd);
```

More clearly, it is the equivalent...

`bash -c 'diff <(sort text2) <(sort text1)'`